# How to get the number between two characters in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have a vector `a`.

I want to extract the numbers between `PUBMED` and `\nREFERENCE`, which means the number is `32634600`

I don't know how to code it using `str_extract()`.

```
a = "234  4dfd 123PUBMED   32634600\nREFERENCE"

# expected output is 32634600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a lookbehind and `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(a, "(?<=PUBMED   )[0-9]+")
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "32634600"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub()` here with a capture group:

```r
a <- "234  4dfd 123PUBMED   32634600\nREFERENCE"
num <- sub(".*PUBMED\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\bREFERENCE\\b.*", "\\1", a)
num

[1] "32634600"
```